# What are the maximum dimensions for a Playground that will appear on all screens?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

The maximum width of a playground is different on different computers. On one of computers (27 inch iMac) the whole live view is visible but some of the live view is cut out on smaller computer.

```
import UIKit  
import PlaygroundSupport  
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1560.0, height: 900.0))  
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red  
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view  
let newview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 1360, y: 0.0, width: 200, height: 200))  
newview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue  
view.addSubview(newview)
```

Here is an example. On my iMac I can see a blue square at the top left of the live view, but on my 15inch Macbook Pro I can't see it, and there is no way to scroll so the blue square is completely cut out from the square.